# google site map generator can't login admin console

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, cgi, mod-ssl, cgi-bin

I installed [Google Sitemap Generator](https://code.google.com/p/googlesitemapgenerator/) for linux x86_64 CentOS 6

But when I try to login to the admin console using this link

`myserverip:8181`

and my password nothing happened.  After refreshing I only got about 20% of the page loaded.

If I try to change the config file to access it from SSL using `https//:` the same problem happens.

I also tried to uninstall it & reinstall, but the same thing still happens.

i used it before from less than 3 months on another server `CentOS 5.9 i386` with no problems

if it fully deprecated any one please knows another tool with the same powerful?

Comment: Are you using this tool? https://code.google.com/p/googlesitemapgenerator/ If so, it hasn't been updated in four years and looks like abandonware.

Comment: Yes i talking about this bit i used it before from less than 3 months on another server `CentOS i386` with no problems if it fully deprecated does you know another tools with the same powerful?

Comment: http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

Comment: @NathanC i have about 150K URL & about 3K daily increasing, the online generators can't do the job, so i need to a server side plugin